# Android Nougat Version - Comma separated string getting wrapped to next line

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android application development and I am currently working on an existing Android application. When I am running my app in the Pixel C device emulator using Android Nougat 7.1.1 version, I have an issue with displaying the comma separated string using TextView. Some part of the text is getting moved to next line automatically even though there is a lot of space for the entire string to display in a single line

Now, I have verified the same case by running the app in the same Pixel C device emulator using Android Pie 9.0 Version but the same comma separated string is getting displayed in the single line without any issue.

Can you please suggest on how to display the comma separated string in the same line such that it supports for all the Android versions.

### Edit

The following is the text view which I am binding the string. The string is coming from the database and it will be of the form something like "course, speechless, talkative". It's just a three word string but the last word talkative is getting moved to next line

```
<TextView android:textIsSelectable="true"
android:id="@+id/mycommaseparatedstring" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: post your code which you tried

Comment: The following is the text view which i am binding the string. The string is coming from the database and it will be of the form something like "course, speechless, talkative" . Its just a three word string but the last word talkative is getting moved to next line

Comment: <TextView
                android:textIsSelectable="true"
                android:id="@+id/mycommaseparatedstring"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

Comment: text will only display to new line if your textview has not enough space left or you string contains too much space i,e newline or \n

Comment: I have not set any width to the textview and the only setting is layout_width which has been set to wrap_content

Comment: you just have textview in layout? did you log your data coming from database?

Comment: It is working fine for the same device when i am using Android Pie Version whereas the issue is getting occurred only for Nougat version. Is there any difference?